# Highlighting Scatterplot Power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, highlight

I have data from different insurance companies.
For these companies I made a scatterplot with Net Premium on the X Axis and Net profit on the y axis.

In the Report I also have 3 bar charts and a table.
I have filters for years, category and company.
The scatterplot ignores the years filter and is filtered by the category filter.

I am trying to highlight the chosen Company in, and only in, the scatterplot.
For example, I filter for a category so my scatterplots shows all data points for the given companies that lie within the category.
Now I want the "company filter" to highlight the data point in my scatterplot.

I tried to do this with conditional formatting but my scatterplot does not take conditional formatting.

I also looked at the method on this site 
http://sqljason.com/2018/03/highlighting-scatter-charts-in-power-bi-using-dax.html
This however is not what I want because I don't want to have another bar chart.

I want my company filter to directly highlight my scatterplot. Does anyone know a way how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by editing your interactions. Select the filter you want to edit the interaction for. You now get a tab format, select it and select "Edit interactions".

In the example below, I selected the Score filter and disable the Employee table from acting on the filter.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this does however not work for my scatterplot. I can use the interactions to highlight other visualisations, but not my scatterplot